# How to draw a battery in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'd like to draw a battery to show the battery level of one of my device that is connected to the phone via bluetooth.

How can I achieve this? I'm a total noob with 2d drawing .... any pointers is helpful

thanks,

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GraphicsDrawingOverview/GraphicsDrawingOverview.html

Comment: "any pointers is helpful" - here you are: `(void *)0xdeadbeef`

Comment: Draw an outline of a battery using a png.  Then fill in the outline by overlaying with a colored rectangle that you adjust the size of.  (The colored rectangle need only be a UIView that you set the backgroundColor of and then adjust it's bounds or frame.)

Comment: @H2CO3 - Clearly his statement was incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to draw a battery to show the battery level of one of my
>   device that is connected to the phone via bluetooth.

Writing code to draw a non-scaling, static image like a battery seems like a lot of trouble. You could do it, of course, but it's so much easier to just draw the image in a drawing program and add it to your app as a resource.

If you want to draw the battery in code, start by sketching the shape on paper or in a drawing program. Then write down a list of all the drawing operations you'll need to do -- for a battery, it's probably just a series of lines and curves. [UIBezierPath](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html) provides those operations, and it's probably easier to start with that than to dive into Quartz2D.

Comment: the thing is i want to fill the battery according to the battery level ....

Comment: Make the interior of the battery transparent and then use the battery image as a mask on top of a colored rectangle. Or, draw the colored rectangle atop the image.

Answer (score 1):

I have done both, using a drawing program, and programmed. Today I find programmed  easier, more fun, and future proof:
You dont have to provide two or how-many-ever-pictures for any change in ios resolution.

A (not so secret) tipp in drawing is, to normalize the drawing between 0 and 1. Then you are independent of battery size.
You achieve that with `CGAffineTransformMakeScale()`. 
But then you immedealty should change the line width to adapt the scale rate:

If you scale by factor r:
lineWidth has to be origLineWidth / r;  // this took me some time to find out!
where for example origLineWidth = 1.0;

Then you could draw:

1. one rectangle for battery corpus, (e.,g from x: 0 to 0.9)
2. one filled rectangle for battery pole. (e.g from x: 0.9 to 1.0)
3. And the charge state of the battery you could use a linear gradient (or better two gradients). One gradient from green to white from y 0 (+ linewidth) - 0.25 and
   another one from white to dark green: y: 0.25 - (1.0 - linewWidth)

Thats is a really nice work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `CGTranformationScale()`. Do you mean `CGAffineTransformMakeScale()`?

Comment: Yes thanks, i am not a living compiler ;-) I will update

Comment: Funnier? Maybe you meant "more fun"? Funnier -> "it makes you laugh more."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little thing I draw in PaintCode, maybe a little to small.

```
CGFloat factor = 0.2; // Something between 0.0 - 1.0

//// Rectangle Drawing
UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, 15, 5)];
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
rectanglePath.lineWidth = 1;
[rectanglePath stroke];


//// Rectangle 2 Drawing -- THIS IS THE INNER "LEVEL" PART
UIBezierPath* rectangle2Path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: CGRectMake(2, 2, 12*factor, 2)];
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
[rectangle2Path fill];
[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
rectangle2Path.lineWidth = 1;
[rectangle2Path stroke];


//// Bezier Drawing
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(15.52, 1.5)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(17.04, 2.97) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(16.64, 1.49) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(17.05, 1.76)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(15.52, 4.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(17.02,         4.16) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(17.05, 4.48)];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(15.52, 1.5) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(15.55, 4.48) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(15.47, 1.49)];
[bezierPath closePath];
[[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
[bezierPath fill];
```